# Remove the container height on toggling visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can toggle the visibility between visible and hidden, also at the same time preserve the properties of display. I have two tabs which toggles between showing a list with all the details of nearby locations and a Bing Map. The problem when I use the display property is that, the map is getting rendered by using the ID of the map.

When I toggle the display property, the search results in Bing Maps are not working as expected. So I am forced to use the visibility property instead. Is there a way I can use visibility to hide and show and at the same time not reserve the height and space of the container that is hidden? I have tried but couldn't come out with a solution. This is what I have tried so far.

**Sample Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  -webkit-padding-start: 15px !important;
  -webkit-padding-end: 15px !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

.results-menu {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.tab-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  visibility: visible;
}

.results-menu {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container results-menu">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="button-default tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">LIST</li>
    <li class="button-default tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">MAP</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  <div class="hidden" id="mapDetails"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
  <div id="myMap" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="legend" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

The toggling works perfect, but I don't want to reserve the height/width of the container div when I toggle. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of adding and removing a class, why not simply use `show()` and `hide()`???

Comment: How about an instant slideUp and slideDown? To make it instant just give it 0 as a time parameter: slideUp(0); slideDown(0);

Comment: @MilanChheda - I can't do that because, the div with ID myMap can't have a display property of none. I am rendering a Bing Map and doing some filtering of results inside. If it has a display none, then the map wouldn't return me the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery or not, this can be easily solved by using the opacity and the pointer-events. You can toggle the classes that apply the `opacity: 1 or 0` and `pointer-events all or none`.

That way the elements and their data stay in place and the UI behaves as expected.

You can have two or more containers e.g. div's one over another, and then just toggle classes on them to show one and hide others. 
By using `opacity` you'll be able to visually hide containers, and by using the `pointer-events` you'll be able to manage the clickability of containers. So, if you would have had 5 containers and wanted to show the third you would set `opacity: 1;` and `pointer-events: all` on the third container and to all other `opacity: 0; pointer-events: none`.

You can apply these styles by switching classes on the containers.

Hope this serves you well :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer pleasE?

Comment: I've extended my answer. You can check it out. Please let me know if you need a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.NOTE:I left some of your classes and styles untouched since I couldn't figure out what you were trying to do.The trick is in jQuery code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $("#" + tab_id).show();
  });
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  -webkit-padding-start: 15px !important;
  -webkit-padding-end: 15px !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

.results-menu {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.tab-content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  visibility: visible;
}

.results-menu {
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container results-menu">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="button-default tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">LIST</li>
    <li class="button-default tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">MAP</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  <div class="hidden" id="mapDetails">This is tab one content</div>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content" style="display:none;">
  <div>This is tab two content</div>
  <div id="myMap" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="legend" style="display:none;">This is tab two content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is what I have mentioned in the description. I am rendering a Bing Map in tab-2 and the ID of the map is used for rendering and searching results in the map. If I give display:none or hide and show, the map wouldn't return me any search results

Comment: A simple fix for me is to set the height of the tab that is not current to be 0px. For example, if tab-1 is current, I have to set the height of the div with ID mapDetails to 0px. Same way, if tab-2 is current, I have to set the height of the div with ID myMap to 0px. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do one dirty fix for the problem I had. The height of the DIV's having ID's "myMap" and "mapDetails" had a fixed height of 670px. When I toggle the visibility between the 2 tabs, I set the height of the other tab to 0px which actually fixed my issue. This is what I did.

```
if(tab_id == "tab-1"){
        console.log("If statement triggered");
        $("#myMap").attr("style", "height:0px;");
        $("#mapDetails").attr("style", "height:670px;");
    }else if(tab_id == "tab-2"){
        console.log("Else If statement triggered");
        $("#mapDetails").attr("style", "height:0px;");
        $("#myMap").attr("style", "height:670px;");
    }else{
        console.log("Else statement triggered");
    }
```